# Xcode generates project template that doesn't compile

Tags: xcode

I'm on Mojave 10.14.6, and installed Xcode 11.3.1. Swift says it's version 5.1.3.
I thought this was OK according to the Xcode release notes:
"Xcode 11.3.1 requires a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.4 or later."
And the notes for Swift said Swift 5.1 needs macOS 10.14.6 and Xcode 11 or later.

In Xcode, when I create a new 'nothing' macos app, Xcode generates this in one of the files:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

When I build this, I get these errors:

- 'some' return types are only available in macOS 10.15.0 or newer
- 'Text' is only available in macOS 10.15 or newer
- 'frame(minWidth:yada:yada:)' is only available in macOS 10.15 or newer

In the project General settings, I set Deployment to 10.14, but that comes too late - the empty app was already generated for 10.15.

In the Build Settings, Deployment is set to 10.14 and the Swift compiler is set to Swift 5.

Is there a way to tell Xcode 11.3.1 to setup a project that will build and run on 10.14.6?

Or do I need to drop back to Xcode 10.3? (the next oldest release?).

Thanks!

EDIT: is it because I used the default SwiftUI?  I just tried Storyboard and the generated code built ok.  So... it's a problem with xcode generating SwiftUI code that Mojave can't build?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Although XC 11.3.1 can run on 10.14.6, the SDK is 10.15.
I went back to XC 10.3, which was the last version with the 10.14 SDK.

This gives Apple Swift version 5.0.1
and Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)

Now I wonder if I can use SwiftUI with Swift 5.0.1 in XC 10.3 on 10.14.6 Mojave?  "*Outlook not so good.*" says Magic 8 Ball. :-)

Thank you [xcodereleases.com](https://xcodereleases.com); I should have looked more carefully before.
Sorry for the noise.